# ssl server and client using python - client is closing the connection due to exception

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I am newbie to socket and ssl programming in python.
Current requirement is that, Client and server shares the pre-shared key so the certificate exchange,authentication and verifying is not needed in both ends. 
So,during **handshake mechanism**, there is no need to authenticate the server from client part but the minimal check is that Cipher suites needs to be send along with random number from client is > **TLS_PSK_WITH_SHA256** and will be acknowledged by server.
In this case, i have created a custom socket instead of Create_default_socket() and passed the parameters TLSv1.2,CERT_NONE and same in client side as well. 
But,when the client is executed, connection is refused due to exception.
Can you point the error in below code , it would certainly help me a lot.
(For testing, i am using HOST - localhost and port - 4443 )

Server code:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
import socket, ssl
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 4443
def handle(conn):
  #print(conn.recv())
  print("entered to handle case")
def main():
  context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
  context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1  # optional
  context.check_hostname = False
  context.set_ciphers('TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA256')
  context.verify_mode=ssl.CERT_NONE
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
  sock.listen(5)
  while True:
    conn = None
    try:
        ssock = context.wrap_socket(sock,server_side=True,
                                   do_handshake_on_connect=False,
                                   suppress_ragged_eofs=False,
                                   session=None
                                   )
        print("created wrap socket")
        conn, addr = ssock.accept()
        handle(conn)
    except ssl.SSLError as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()
```

print("Executing server main fn call")
main()

Client code:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.check_hostname=False
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1  # optional
context.verify_mode =ssl.CERT_NONE
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
conn = context.wrap_socket(sock,
                           server_side=False,
                           do_handshake_on_connect=False,
                           suppress_ragged_eofs=False,
                           server_hostname=HOST)
try:
    conn.connect((HOST, PORT))
    #handle(conn)
except ssl.SSLError as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    if conn:
        conn.close()
        print("client is closed due to exception")
```

Getting Errors in server side :
if sock.getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE) != SOCK_STREAM:
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Error in Client side - connection is closed due to exception.

Comment: Please provide the whole stack trace and all the code which is part of the stack trace. I suspect that the error is produced inside your `handle` function on the server but you don't show any code of this function. Also, if you use a PSK cipher you actually need to provide this pre shared key both in client and server (that's why it is called __pre__ shared) - but there is nothing like this in your code.

Comment: 1/ Handler code in server is not having actual code as of now, but you can have a look now.  2/ Pre-Shared keys are not exchanged in handshake step as per requirement , instead the key_ID is passed, from which key value in both the ends will fetch the key value.

Comment: Still no full stack trace as requested. Regarding *"instead the key_ID is passed"* - your code does not do this either.

Comment: I don't know, how to pass or set the PSK key(eg - let's take key value as AC) by using SSL module @SteffenUllrich Can you help in this , if you know it